# TYPO3 - How to set rootUid for categories of DCE content elements?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In a multi-domain TYPO3 (10.4) installation with websites in different languages, with a lot of sys categories (each language has its own sys category tree), it quickly becomes confusing.

My question:
How can I define the rootUid of a specific sys category tree for DCE (tx_dce) content elements?

This works for common typo3 content elements even for gridelements but not for DCE content elements:
`TCEFORM.tt_content.categories.config.treeConfig.rootUid = 123`

Comment: In the field `tx_dce_dce` there are no categories to select. Do you mean the field `categories` of table `tt_content`?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler yes, I mean the field categories when you edit the dce content-elements (tt_content).

Comment: Is this field inside an DCE element? There is also a default category field in tt_content.

Comment: Which table / field is this category selection?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler
No, I mean the default category field of an DCE element.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler
I have adjusted my question, from "startingPoints" to "rootUid".
The rootUid definition should affect all DCE elements no matter what fields they have, see my screenshot: ![](https://www.bugfree-systems.de/tmp/Screenshot_DCE-categories_2022-01-13.png)

Comment: You need to be careful to use the documentation for your version. Your linked documentation document is for latest TYPO3 core. You are using v10 where `startingPoints` don't exist: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/10.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#config-treeconfig

Comment: Please add your TCA definition of the DCE element into your question. Without that it's hard to give you the correct configuration.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler I got It. This is how it works: `TCEFORM.tt_content.selected_categories.config.treeConfig.rootUid = 123`

Comment: Nice! Please set your solution as answer here, so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works:
`TCEFORM.tt_content.selected_categories.config.treeConfig.rootUid = 123`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).